# Where is the exclusivity violation in this Swift + CoreData view?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm a bit stumped on this one. I have two core data entities: Person and Memory. Memory has a people field that is a "to many" relationship to Person, and Person has a memories field that is a "to many" relationship to Memory.

I created a PeopleForm view to manage the people associated with a memory. The memory object gets passed in as an @ObservedObject to the view. I want to list the people, but people is an NSSet, so I created a computed property called peopleArray that converts the NSSet to [Person] (and sorts it for good measure).

I use the ForEach view with peopleArray to create a list of people. I use the onDelete view modifier to let the user remove a person from the list of people for that memory. The onDelete calls the removePerson function, which looks up the person object in peopleArray by the index, and then passes it to the memory object's removeFromPeople() method.

The removeFromPeople() method appears to be what triggers the runtime error. I've ready about exclusivity enforcement, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong here.
The following is a pared down version of my code:

```swift
struct PeopleForm: View {
    @ObservedObject var memory: Memory
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    private var peopleArray: [Person] {
        get {
            Array(memory.people as! Set<Person>).sorted {
                $0.displayName < $1.displayName
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(peopleArray) { person in
                    Text(person.displayName)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removePerson)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func removePerson(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { index in
            let person = peopleArray[index]

            viewContext.perform {
                memory.removeFromPeople(person)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to note that the stack trace points at the @main decorator on my App object declaration, which I understand is a symptom of a crash occurring within objc code. The error does not occur when stepping through the code line by line in the debugger, but I also can't step into the removeFromPeople method that is generated from my data model. If I step through to the removeFromPeople line and resume, the error occurs, so it seems to be something internal to CoreData that is going on here. Sure enough, the CoreData generated removeFromPeople method is objective c code for which I don't know how to see the implementation.

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x117406ef0, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at SwiftUI`<redacted> + 156 (0x198684c4c).
Current access (a read) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a59c8 <redacted> + 432
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a5bf0 swift_beginAccess + 84
2    SwiftUI                            0x0000000198599250 <redacted> + 28
3    SwiftUI                            0x000000019926b5e0 <redacted> + 44
4    SwiftUI                            0x00000001985a5658 <redacted> + 124
5    SwiftUI                            0x000000019937a078 <redacted> + 104
6    SwiftUI                            0x000000019937a0fc <redacted> + 236
7    UIKitCore                          0x0000000193e74fbc <redacted> + 124
8    UIKitCore                          0x000000019329a428 <redacted> + 212
9    UIKitCore                          0x00000001932e2fb4 <redacted> + 1100
10   UIKitCore                          0x000000019310d2b0 <redacted> + 136
11   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f41030 <redacted> + 532
12   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f7015c <redacted> + 96
13   UIKitCore                          0x000000019329aa58 <redacted> + 72
14   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192fb6340 <redacted> + 436
15   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198699f5c <redacted> + 64
16   SwiftUI                            0x000000019865abf0 <redacted> + 16
17   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a83ec <redacted> + 56
18   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198699f5c <redacted> + 64
19   SwiftUI                            0x000000019865abf0 <redacted> + 16
20   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a83ec <redacted> + 56
21   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198699f5c <redacted> + 64
22   SwiftUI                            0x000000019865abf0 <redacted> + 16
23   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a83ec <redacted> + 56
24   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000019579b060 swift_arrayDestroy + 124
25   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198fe3c84 <redacted> + 44
26   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198fe39ac <redacted> + 116
27   SwiftUI                            0x00000001987883dc <redacted> + 40
28   libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001957a83ec <redacted> + 56
29   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001c2e76a70 <redacted> + 152
30   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001c2e76178 <redacted> + 1260
31   AttributeGraph                     0x00000001c2e75cc8 <redacted> + 264
32   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198684bb0 <redacted> + 188
33   SwiftUI                            0x00000001985cd1a0 <redacted> + 84
34   SwiftUI                            0x00000001985c7758 _UIHostingView.__deallocating_deinit + 228
35   SwiftUI                            0x00000001985d25ac <redacted> + 28
36   SwiftUI                            0x0000000198718618 <redacted> + 36
37   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001a964027c <redacted> + 116
38   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001a963d0f4 objc_destructInstance + 80
39   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001a9646964 _objc_rootDealloc + 80
40   UIKitCore                          0x00000001930be6c8 <redacted> + 156
41   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f89278 <redacted> + 1220
42   CoreFoundation                     0x000000019095ebd4 <redacted> + 116
43   CoreFoundation                     0x0000000190972848 <redacted> + 276
44   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f89278 <redacted> + 1184
45   UIKitCore                          0x00000001931569bc <redacted> + 448
46   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001a963f9b0 <redacted> + 196
47   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001a963bd20 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 212
48   UIKitCore                          0x00000001930e8cf0 <redacted> + 92
49   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192ffc008 <redacted> + 192
50   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f25664 <redacted> + 644
51   UIKitCore                          0x0000000192f25f88 <redacted> + 132
52   UIKitCore                          0x00000001932fe990 <redacted> + 84
53   UIKitCore                          0x0000000193599030 <redacted> + 84
54   UIKitCore                          0x0000000193c1ec20 <redacted> + 144
55   UIKitCore                          0x0000000193c1e41c <redacted> + 92
56   CoreFoundation                     0x0000000190a0bee8 <redacted> + 28
57   CoreFoundation                     0x0000000190a1cbc0 <redacted> + 208
58   CoreFoundation                     0x0000000190956078 <redacted> + 268
59   CoreFoundation                     0x000000019095b810 <redacted> + 828
60   CoreFoundation                     0x000000019096f460 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
61   GraphicsServices                   0x00000001aca092d0 GSEventRunModal + 164
62   UIKitCore                          0x00000001932d4a3c <redacted> + 1100
63   UIKitCore                          0x0000000193056480 UIApplicationMain + 364
64   SwiftUI                            0x00000001987a659c <redacted> + 164
65   SwiftUI                            0x00000001986d4428 <redacted> + 252
66   SwiftUI                            0x00000001986b5790 static App.main() + 128
67   Matter                             0x0000000104b657d8 static MatterApp.$main() + 40
68   Matter                             0x0000000104b65938 main + 12
```

Comment: There should be an error message in console, could you show the full error?

Comment: Why are you using perform ? Have initialised your context as specified [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506578-perform) ?

Comment: @Larme I have attached the error output.

Comment: @PtitXav My viewContext is initialized using the same code that is in the Xcode iOS app with CoreData and CloudKit template. The perform call was only added as a suggestion based on another Stack Overflow answer, but the error still occurs. I have since removed that.

Comment: You may be doing 2 access at the same time because you remove a person from memory which will remove it from memory people which will remove it from peopleArray. Did you try to remove the memory from the people instead : people.removeFromMemory(memory) ?

Comment: The crash seems to be related to SwiftUI rather than Core Data.  I would try to change the `removePerson` function so that each person to be deleted was added to a Set and then I would call `memory.removeFromPeople` with the set _after_ the `forEach` loop

Comment: I agree with the last comment. I don’t think you can call on an Entity when it’s an observed object. I would recommend you get it with a @Fetchrequest, then you have the context correctly set up, or do the function in the parent view

Comment: Have you tried extending the entity `Memory` with the `peopleArray` computed variable, then you can just use `memory.peopleArray` in the view. I think this may avoid the issues you are having in your view with the crash. Paul Hegarty uses this technique in [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/).

Comment: @PtitXav Your suggestion ended up solving the problem for me, though I ended I scrapping this whole approach to the view after reviewing the experience once I got it working.

Comment: To the other commenters, thanks for the responses. I suspect your suggestions might have also gotten me back on the right track if I had kept the design of the view as described.

Answer (score 0):

The design is not quite right. `PeopleForm` needs a `@FetchRequest` for `People` with an `NSPredicate(format: "memory == %@", memory)`, e.g.

```
struct PeopleForm: View {
    private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<People>
    private var people: FetchedResults< People > {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }

     init(memory: Memory) {
        let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\People.timestamp, order: sortAscending ? .forward : .reverse)]
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "memory = %@", memory), animation: .default)
    }
```